# Why not put short-term savings in the market?

Tags: savings, short-term

My income comes entirely at the end of the year so I'm planning out where I should put my expenses for the year. The general advice I've seen is that you shouldn't put money into the stock market if you'll need it within a year or two, but I'm questioning that advice for my personal situation where my savings (mostly in cash and broad index funds) is much greater than my expenses.

I could do one of:

1. put the money in a high interest savings account and get 4.5%

   - no risk
   - slightly faster to access the cash
2. put the money into stocks and get higher returns on average but be exposed to short term fluctuations

   - higher transaction costs (but index ETFs are extremely liquid and stock trading is free)
   - if market goes down

     - I'll have losses
     - I'll sell the dip (i.e. a larger quantity of shares)
     - I'll deduct the capital losses which will help offset other gains
     - I'll still have plenty of savings for the long term
   - if market goes up

     - I'll have gains (but I can sell old tax-lots to avoid short-term gains)
     - I'll pay taxes on the gains

Am I wrong to think the benefits of the market could outweigh the risks? Am I missing some other downside or misunderstanding the costs? I'm guessing the general advice is geared towards risk-averse folks and those with less savings.

Comment: That is extremely broad, similar to "stock market generally goes up, why don't we keep money there all the time". You should take your strategy and run it on historical data (say, last 5 years). I suspect that you are greatly underestimate risks and trading fees which will eat into your profits when you need to pull emergency $20k for new roof on your house

Comment: on average, [10 days per decade are making all the gains in market](https://www.cnbc.com/2021/03/24/this-chart-shows-why-investors-should-never-try-to-time-the-stock-market.html). What are the chances you'll need money during other 3640 days?

Comment: "10 day per decade are making all the gains" -  surely this doesn't mean you have to sell on the exact right day. I'm not trying to time the market, just maximize the amount and time in the market.

Comment: "...trading fees which will eat into your profits" - the bid-ask spread for e.g. SPY is .01 which is .2% or .4% round trip, which is a good point. Based on that it seems safe to say that anything less than 3 months is probably negative expectancy. Can you elaborate on the risks? that's what my question is about and it seems like you have an answer in mind.

Comment: you know enough to (a) run simulation of your strat or (b) hire a professional to help with your specific plan

Comment: "emergency $20k for new roof on your house" - I'm talking about normal expenses here. either way i'd separately have an emergency fund in a very safe account.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have a decent grasp of the risk and pitfalls.

If you have a certain amount of money that could lose half its value overnight and then take two to three years to return to its original value then it can be invested.  While this is an extreme circumstance it is a decent litmus test.

Another way to approach this is to some money in safe high yield savings, and some invested in the market.   If you do 50% in each, then even if the market does lose half its value you still have 75% of your savings.

Please considering looking into bonds to boost your "safe" earnings rate.  Shorter term corporate bonds are returning well over 6%.  Currently I am pretty active in this area.

Answer (score 0):

So based on some comments above I've gotten some ideas:

- just crossing the bid-ask spread could easily reach .5% which rules out any strategy involving holding for very short periods
- based on my naive and simplistic spreadsheet backtesting just looking at SPX over the last 5 years, which for better or for worse contains the 2020 COVID roller coaster:

  - for 1 month holding periods, 32% had negative nominal returns, the worst was -49% return and the mean was .9% (11.1% annualized)
  - for 3 month holding periods, 32% had negative nominal returns, the worst was -28% return and the mean was 3.6% (14.3% annualized)
  - for 6 month holding periods, 28% had negative nominal returns, the worst was -25% return and the mean was 7.4% (14.8% annualized)
  - for 9 month holding periods, 29% had negative nominal returns, the worst was -21% return and the mean was 11.6% (15.5% annualized)

So my conclusion is that these are all pretty risky in that they have a good chance of being significantly negative. On the other hand all the typical returns are way above the best high-interest savings account.

I'm still pretty unsure if I'm missing any other factors.

Comment: Just looking at the last 5 years is very short for doing this kind of analysis. You want much longer time periods. Even if you do, there is no guarantee that the next three years are like any of the last 50.